# Jquery ajax success when upgrading from 1.3.2 to 1.8.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I have a problem :)

I upgraded my old jquery 1.3.2 to newest version 1.8.3.

Of course, upgrading from such an old version will cause problem with my custom jquery code :)

I figured out that I should use proxy instead of bind, but I still have problem with my ajax code.

I am not a experienced javascript debugger but to me it seems like ajax success doesn't trigger my Google Chrome breakpoint in setProgress.

My code:

```
getProgress: function() {
    $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "/progress", dataType: "json",
      beforeSend: $.proxy(function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Progress-ID", this.uuid);
      }, this),
      success: $.proxy(this.setProgress, this)
    });
  },
  setProgress: function(data) {
    if (data.state == "done") {
      this.finished();
    } else if (data.state == "error") {
      alert("ERROR"+data.status);
      this.finished();
    } else if (data.state == "starting") {
      this.statusText.text("Startar");
      this.setTime();
    } else {
      bps = bytesPerSecond((new Date()).getTime()-this.lastTime, this.received, data.received);
      this.lastTime = (new Date()).getTime()
      try { remaining = (this.size-this.received)/bps; } catch(err) { remaining = 0; }
      this.received = data.received;
      this.size = data.size;
      this.statusText.html(
        (this.received/this.size).toPercentage()+
        "&nbsp;Uppladdat&nbsp;(&nbsp;"+
        data.received.toHumanSize()+
        "&nbsp;av&nbsp;"+
        data.size.toHumanSize()+
        "&nbsp;)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+
        bps.toHumanSize()+
        "/s&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+
        timeLeft(remaining)+
        "&nbsp;kvar"
      );
      this.statusText.width((this.progressBar.width()-40)*(this.received/this.size)+20);
      this.setTime();
    }
  },
```

I guess there has been some changes to ajax in jquery 1.4+ that breaks my code. Any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution for this :)

It was not really the code that caused the problem. It was my Nginx conf that didn't output pure json which jquery now validates in version 1.4+ (thats why it worked in jquery 1.3.2 and not in newer versions).

So I added this to my Nginx conf:

```
location ^~ /progress {
  upload_progress_json_output;
  report_uploads proxied;
}
```